# javascript: find URL of new window

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage which displays dynamically generated content from another website with lots of hyperlinks.

Clicking on these hyperlinks results in the opening of either a new tab or window - depending on the browser's settings.

Is there any way that I can detect the URL of the page that is opened on the click?

I am thinking I should use Javascript in my own page with a "Body onload" kind of listener.

Any ideas are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Uttam

Comment: When the user clicks on a link that opens a new window, is its `href` attribute be the window's URL, or is it more complicated than that in your case?

Comment: Can you add event listeners on the links?  If so, there's a number of good solutions there.

Comment: jQuery code: $("a").click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
});

Comment: @Brian: Not complicated - the links simply open up a new window/tab.

Comment: @ChristianDuvall:  I may be able to add event listeners - though I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can do this very easily:

```
   $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
      var $anchor = $(this),
          url = $anchor.prop('href');

      // Use the url variable here.

   });
```

This will create and event handler for the `document` that will trigger whenever an anchor is clicked.